# MySQL Create update/insert trigger on a table

Tags: mysql, triggers

Is it possible to create a trigger in mysql for this:

I have a table like this

```
Column1_id Column2_val
 1            2
 2            2
```

Second table

```
Column1_id1 Column2_id2
    1           2
```

So pretty much on update or insert if twos rows have the same value for `Column2_val` I want to insert the ids of that into the second table. any help would be greatly appriciated.

I wrote this but it doesn't seem to be working am i doing something wrong?

```
BEGIN
    set @user_id_update =  (SELECT Column1_id from users where in_play = 2 LIMIT 1);
    INSERT INTO player_pairs(PLAYER1_ID, PLAYER2_ID, GAME_ID) 
    VALUES (new.Column1_id, @user_id_update, 2); 
    UPDATE users  SET in_play = 1 where Column1_id in(@user_id_update, new.user_id);
END
```

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html)

Comment: Add some more information about what you want

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this

```
DELIMITER $$

    CREATE TRIGGER test AFTER INSERT, UPDATE ON `table1`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
      SET x = (SELECT count(*) FROM `table1` WHERE Column2_val=NEW.Column2_val)
      IF (x > 1) THEN
            INSERT INTO `table2` VALUES(NEW.Column1_id, NEW.Column2_val)
      END IF;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks, but but im not trying to insert the new id and the new val to table 2. I want to add the new id and another old id which is not same as the current row where the value is 2. which doesnt seem to be working when i do update trigger

Comment: @user1884193 are you saying that something is wrong in the way you want to insert in table2 or the triggers are not working?

Comment: the triggers aren't working. I just used java to accomplish the task. Thanks guys.

Comment: Please post your answer for further understanding of the solution and it may help other.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one and let me know:

```
DELIMITER $$

    CREATE TRIGGER test AFTER INSERT, UPDATE ON `table1`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
      IF (select count(Column2_val) from `table1` WHERE Column2_val=NEW.Column2_val> 0 ) THEN
            INSERT INTO `table2` VALUES(NEW.Column1_id, NEW.Column2_val)
      END IF;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

However, if you want to have any dublicate records on any column of the first table you can make this column "Unique".